# Installation shows no disk space available

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, macbook-pro

The problem is that the installer doesn’t see enough space
I have a 2017 MacBook Pro and I made a partition with 100 GB MS_DOS FAT GUID. Look at the pictures.

[image: installer window]

Gparted:
[image]

Comment: can you take a screenshot on your GParted?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. You should leave your Drive partitionless upon install or create an ext4 Partition for ubuntu. Otherwise it will not detect space to install in.

Comment: I want to dual boot with Mac OS, so how can I leave the drive partitionless?

Comment: How can I make ext4 partition, I can’t see that format in disk Utility in the Mac OS

Comment: @mondjunge I installed ubuntu 16.04 and it is working fine, I don't know why 14.04 is not detecting the space

Comment: @Blkc this is also something that popped when I started Gparted (https://imgur.com/a/NBPlAEg)

Comment: Your Gparted image doesn't match your question. See [my  answer.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056973/225694) If that doesn't clarify the situation for you please [edit] your question to include the output in text from the command `sudo fdisk -l | grep sd` and I'll update my answer accordingly. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek sorry for the late answer, this is the fdisk -l output ( https://imgur.com/a/eTFN5N9 )

Comment: @Mask114 _“I installed ubuntu 16.04 and it is working fine, I don't know why 14.04 is not detecting the space”_ Is there any reason to install 14.04? 16.04 utilizes two more years of development, so this might be one of the problems which were solved in between.

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself "please [edit] your question to include the output in *text*

Answer (score 0):

Remove your 100 MB FAT partition again and leave the space empty. After that, the installer will use the free space taken by that partition you created.

Ubuntu needs empty, unformatted and unpartitioned space for automated installation next to another operating system. Either it will use unallocated space that is there, or first automatically shrink partitions (e.g. automatically installing besides Windows - I am not sure if the Ubuntu installation utility can resize a Mac partition).

Of course, advanced users can also create the partitions themselves and indicate in the installer how the partitions should be taken into use.

Comment: I’m a beginner, so I’m really not sure how to remove it, do you mean erasing it from disk Utility? Btw I want to duel boot Ubuntu with my Mac OS

Comment: This isn't really true I think - the installer will happily make and format partitions over pretty much whatever is there

Comment: @Zanna, yes, if you instruct it to erase the entire disk. There are multiple options upon an Ubuntu install, so this is not simply a matter of yes or no. I will try to incorporate this in my answer

Comment: @Mask114 Yes, erasing that partition with the same tool with which you created it should do the trick. (disk utility from Mac?)

Comment: @vanadium but I already have more space left on my drive, what will be different if I erase this partition. I use Mac disk utility

Comment: @Mask114 if you erase that partition, the installer might have sufficient room to install Ubuntu. The alternative would be to have it overwrite other partitions, which you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me from your gparted image like you are attempting to install Ubuntu on a 4GB flash drive. This will fail regardless of what you do with your partitions as 6.8GB is the bare minimum as reported by the installer. I know this isn't the answer you want but it's the best your going to get with the information currently available.